# How can I make GRPC server run on another web server (not netty)

Tags: java, webserver, netty, grpc, grpc-java

Grpc Server seems to be implemented using netty. Is there a way to use other implementations ?

Answer (score 4):

Netty is the only supported server. You can either have two separate ports (one for your other server, one for gRPC) or could reverse proxy from your other server to the Netty server.

There is [work underway](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/4738) ([tracking issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1621)) to allow serving using the Servlet API, so then any Servlet Container could be used. But there are restrictions, like the needing to be the root ('/') webapp. It is far enough along to test it and provide feedback, but there also may be some gaps in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks again, Eric! You've been a lot of help answering my questions.